# Why do we use following code while reading JSON file or request object in java?

Tags: java, json, regex, request, delimiter

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
```

What is the significance of `"\\A"` here? As far as I know this will match literally `\A`

Also I have seen people using `"\\Z"` at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

In regex

- \A indicates start of String
- \z indicates end of String

For more details, refer below the link.

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Any comment on code part ? What I am understanding is that using useDelimiter("\\A") we are dividing the string and finding its actual content using .hasNext()